# Where are the inline remote settings in Android?

Tags: headphones, remote-control

I recently purchased a set of headphones with iPhone controls. I've never had these work on Android before and was expecting to just get audio out, and lo and behold, I have media controls.

The trouble seems to be, I also have Voice Dialing, which is triggering itself anytime the headphones are plugged in. Any app playing music now also pauses and plays randomly.

I don't know exactly what's going on, but I suspect that there are 2-3 different apps all trying to do something with the headset, and it's causing problems. I don't really need it to work, but I can't find *any* settings dealing with the inline remote anywhere. I've been digging through the system settings and all of my app settings all day and nothing even mentions these behaviors.

I don't care if I have to recompile the kernel myself; I very much want to edit this behavior. Where do I start looking? Is the headset a hardware button? Is there a flag I can check for with an app's code that can detect when a headset with a remote is plugged in to make it do different things?

Comment: Are the headphones made specifically for iPhone?

Comment: You don't have the Turntable app installed, do you? I had all kinds of weird randomness with headphones while I had that installed.

Comment: Yeah, the headphones are specifically made for iPhone. That's what surprised me; I wasn't expecting them to do anything at all.

Comment: There is a spec about headsets and the expected behavior of the button(s) on android.com: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/expected-behavior

Answer (score 3):

To my experience, headset control behaved randomly. Took me a couple of weeks to figure out why suddenly in my training sessions the music player started (wow! that button on the headset suddenly does something...). Like you, I never found any corresponding system settings.

To get rid of that "random system", I took a look around. As usual with Android, almost everything is triggering (or triggered by) an intent, and a listener reacts on that. If there are multiple listeners, the user will be asked with which app to perform the action -- and can declare that app the standard; which holds until a new app registers or the chosen app gets uninstalled.

That said, I went to the Playstore and took a look around -- and indeed, there are multiple apps around taking care of the button-presses: Single press, double, triple, long-hold, klick-and-hold... I never imagined how much to do with a single button :D Unfortunately for me, I could not yet convince the one app I tried to behave as intended -- except for single click and single hold (i.e. play/stop/take-call and volume-up) -- but that may be due to the combination of headset/phone/app, and I certainly will try to figure this out by evaluating different apps.

To give you a starting point: there's e.g. [JAYS Headset Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol), which I currently use. Though highly configurable<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iITID.jpg)</sup>, see above for my problems (Philips plugs, Motorola device). Then there's also [Headset Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tvk.headvol) which looks quite promising<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKdg.jpg)</sup>, but costs about EUR 2. This seems to support multiple buttons even, from the screenshots.

[image: JAYS] [image: Headset Droid]

Then there are [Headset Button Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton) (also about EUR 2), [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) (free -- the next one I should try with my Philips headset), and a lot more -- just search the playstore for "headsetbutton"...

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Headset button controller**. This worked for me.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton&hl=en

There is a trial version for this too.

Comment: That app is my best preference as well, but do you realize the question was asked 4 years ago?? For that reason, you'll need to elaborate on how Headset Button Controller works. Include instructions and screenshots, so your answer will be thorough and professional.